# Excel VBA - Text to Date after running macro in a single Row

Tags: excel, vba

I have several Macros running at once in a file. The output pastes unique dates from B1:Z1 on the next sheet. The dates right now are pasting as ex. 43619 instead of 6/3/2019. I have been troubleshooting this but everything I have found is a whole column instead of rows. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Excel a Date is a number(the number of days since 1/1/1900).  The number is formatted to look like a date.

If you are just pasting the values the format is not following and as such the value is reverted to the number.

To apply the formatting just use:

```
Worksheet("Sheet1").Range("B1:Z1").NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
```

Changing the sheet name to your desired sheet and the number format to the format desired.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Scott Craner . here is my current code . `Sub format()
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Set sht = Worksheet("Sheet2").Range("B1:Z1").NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
End Sub` It is currently giving me an error

Comment: Sorry I am new to VBA. Do I just simply write the code `Sub format() Worksheet("Sheet1").Range("B1:Z1").NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy" End Sub` ??

Comment: Yes but change the `"Sheet1"` to the correct sheet name.